# IDML package import seems to work but nothing show in the document

Tags: validation, import, idml

I've created a package idml and imported it without error into InDesign.

It contains backingstorys and associated images. None of them have previously been placed into a document/layout.

Nothing appears after the import is done.

Is this expected behaviour?

Should the backing stories appear? How do I place them if the don't appear?

I've tried to get a validation tool and asked on the Adobe forums. I've asked for paid support from Adobe and still end up waiting weeks to get someone who will help me.

Thanks for responding!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
```

-

mimetype file contents
    application/vnd.adobe.indesign-idml-package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
```

-

-

-

-

-
Headline: Bannana, rank: 5.5, word count: 12, photos: 4 the title name here  content 1 the title name here content 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
```

-

-

-

-

Headline: the headline HL 2 , rank: 5.4, word count: 12, photos: 0 the content here

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question with help from Adobe Technology Partners.

I've got a working way to dynamically generate IDML with pictures.

IDML is a zip file which contains other files. This is a simple example of a working IDML file (structure).

The first file in an .idml (zipped) file is named:
mimetype

It must contain:
application/vnd.adobe.indesign-idml-package

The next file in an .idml (zipped) file is named:
designmap.xml

Here is an example of a working designmap.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?aid style="50" type="document" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="257"?>
<Document xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0" Self="d">
<idPkg:Spread src="Spreads/Spread_2176.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2214.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2176.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_asset_230.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_asset_231.xml"/>
</Document>
```

Next in this example the .idml (zipped) are two folders: 
Spreads
Stories

In this example the Spreads folder contains a single Spread_2227.xml document. Here is the contents of Spread_2227.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Spread xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
    <Spread Self="spread_2214" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
        <Page Self="Page_1" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="headline for this story" >
            <TextFrame Self="textframe_2214" ParentStory="story_2214" ContentType="TextType" >
                <Properties>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                            <PathPointArray>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
                            </PathPointArray>
                        </GeometryPathType>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Properties>
            </TextFrame>
        </Page>
    </Spread>
    <Spread Self="spread_2176" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
        <Page Self="Page_2" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="headline of story 2176" >
            <TextFrame Self="textframe_2176" ParentStory="story_2176" ContentType="TextType" >
                <Properties>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
                            <PathPointArray>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
                                <PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
                            </PathPointArray>
                        </GeometryPathType>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Properties>
            </TextFrame>
        </Page>
    </Spread>
</idPkg:Spread>
```

In this example the Stories folder contains for xml documents. Story_2176.xml, Story_2214.xml,Story_asset_231.xml, Story_asset_230.xml  Here is the contents of Stories folder:
        
    
       
          Headline: headline of story 2176, rank: null, word count: 5, photos: 0

```
body content of this story.</Content>
   </Story>
</idPkg:Story>



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
   <Story Self="story_2176">
      <Content>Headline: headline of story 2176, rank: null, word count: 5, photos: 0

body content of this story.</Content>
   </Story>
</idPkg:Story>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
   <Story Self="cutline_231">
      <Content>002</Content>
   </Story>
</idPkg:Story>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
   <Story Self="cutline_230">
      <Content>013</Content>
   </Story>
</idPkg:Story>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Backing stories are hidden in the structure pane. To place them, show the structure pane and drag one of the XML nodes into a frame.

If your goal is to have text and images show up on a layout, create a layout that looks the way you'd like your IDML file to look when you open it in InDesign. Then export that layout as IDML and examine the contents.

Here you'll see that text on a page is a Story_XXX.xml file inside the Story folder. This is reference by the Spread_XXX.xml file inside the Spreads folder. The Spread_XXX.xml file will also define where images and other objects appear.

Comment: I viewed the Structure pane and nothing shows there. If I import the various XML documents individually portions of them appear.

I need to validate the package. 

I've tried repeatedly to get someone from Adobe to point me to a download where I can get the app to validate IDML. After finally speaking with someone at Adobe today, they transferred me to their technical support line. 1:47 minutes later I hung up waiting, with nothing but wait music coming through...

Can you help me get my IDML validated?

Comment: Thanks to the help of many I worked out correct IDML for my application. I'm going to post the example in hopes it will save someone else the trouble I had.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the answer to this question, since I'm the one who asked the question. Backing story was the wrong way to go. I'll include her a valid IDML file, which is nothing more than a zip file renamed as IDML.

The first file in an IDML file must be named: MIMETYPE, and must contain:"application/vnd.adobe.indesign-idml-package"

The second file in my application is designmap.xml and it contains a reference to my single spread and each story in that spread. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?aid style="50" type="document" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="257"?>
<Document xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0" Self="d">
<idPkg:Spread src="Spreads/Spread_2868.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2596.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2597.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2599.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2601.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_2642.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_asset_1019.xml"/>
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_asset_985.xml"/>
</Document>
```

The next item in my IDML is a folder named Spreads, which in my application contains a single Spread_nnnn.xml file, since my application only uses a single spread. My shortened Spread_nnnn.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Spread xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
<Spread Self="spread_2596" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
<Page Self="Page_1" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="2016 focus on public safety" >
<TextFrame Self="textframe_2596" ParentStory="story_2596" ContentType="TextType" >
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
</Page>
</Spread>
<Spread Self="spread_2597" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
<Page Self="Page_2" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="Cummings makes move south" >
<TextFrame Self="textframe_2597" ParentStory="story_2597" ContentType="TextType" >
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
<TextFrame Self="thisCutline_1019" ParentStory="cutline_1019" ContentType="TextType" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 41 -196">
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 0" LeftDirection="0 0" RightDirection="0 0"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 15" LeftDirection="0 15" RightDirection="0 15"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="107.78947368421052 15" LeftDirection="107.78947368421052 15" RightDirection="107.78947368421052 15"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="107.78947368421052  0" LeftDirection="107.78947368421052  0" RightDirection="107.78947368421052  0"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
<Rectangle Self="rectangle_1019" StrokeWeight="0" ContentType="GraphicType" Visible="true" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 41 -180">
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPath PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 0" LeftDirection="0 0" RightDirection="0 0"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 71.84210526315789" LeftDirection="0 71.84210526315789" RightDirection="0 71.84210526315789"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="107.78947368421052 71.84210526315789" LeftDirection="107.78947368421052 71.84210526315789" RightDirection="107.78947368421052 71.84210526315789"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="107.78947368421052 0" LeftDirection="107.78947368421052 0" RightDirection="107.78947368421052 0"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPath>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
<Image Self="image_1019" ImageTypeName="$ID/JPEG" Visible="true" Name="$ID/c_Chief_Engineering_John_Cummings_family_1019.jpg">
<Link Self="ucc" LinkResourceURI="file://~/Downloads/Images_for_AMExpress_75_Jan_15_DwW2/c_Chief_Engineering_John_Cummings_family_1019.jpg"/>
</Image>
</Rectangle>
</Page>
</Spread>
<Spread Self="spread_2599" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
<Page Self="Page_3" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="Engineering projects abound in 2015, 2016" >
<TextFrame Self="textframe_2599" ParentStory="story_2599" ContentType="TextType" >
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
</Page>
</Spread>
<Spread Self="spread_2601" PageCount="1" BindingLocation="0" >
<Page Self="Page_4" GeometricBounds="0 0 792 559" Name="Updating the fleet" >
<TextFrame Self="textframe_2601" ParentStory="story_2601" ContentType="TextType" >
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 41" LeftDirection="41 41" RightDirection="41 41"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="41 191" LeftDirection="41 191" RightDirection="41 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559 191" LeftDirection="559 191" RightDirection="559 191"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="559  41" LeftDirection="559  41" RightDirection="559  41"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
<TextFrame Self="thisCutline_985" ParentStory="cutline_985" ContentType="TextType" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 41 -196">
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPathType PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 0" LeftDirection="0 0" RightDirection="0 0"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 15" LeftDirection="0 15" RightDirection="0 15"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="42.54545454545455 15" LeftDirection="42.54545454545455 15" RightDirection="42.54545454545455 15"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="42.54545454545455  0" LeftDirection="42.54545454545455  0" RightDirection="42.54545454545455  0"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPathType>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
</TextFrame>
<Rectangle Self="rectangle_985" StrokeWeight="0" ContentType="GraphicType" Visible="true" ItemTransform="1 0 0 1 41 -180">
<Properties>
<PathGeometry>
<GeometryPath PathOpen="false">
<PathPointArray>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 0" LeftDirection="0 0" RightDirection="0 0"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="0 22.454545454545453" LeftDirection="0 22.454545454545453" RightDirection="0 22.454545454545453"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="42.54545454545455 22.454545454545453" LeftDirection="42.54545454545455 22.454545454545453" RightDirection="42.54545454545455 22.454545454545453"/>
<PathPoint Anchor="42.54545454545455 0" LeftDirection="42.54545454545455 0" RightDirection="42.54545454545455 0"/>
</PathPointArray>
</GeometryPath>
</PathGeometry>
</Properties>
<Image Self="image_985" ImageTypeName="$ID/JPEG" Visible="true" Name="$ID/c_Tracie_Loredo_new_cars_985.jpg">
<Link Self="ucc" LinkResourceURI="file://~/Downloads/Images_for_AMExpress_75_Jan_15_DwW2/c_Tracie_Loredo_new_cars_985.jpg"/>
</Image>
</Rectangle>
</Page>
</Spread>
</idPkg:Spread>
```

The next item in the IDML file is a folder named Stories, which contains a Story_nnnn.xml file for each story content. Here is an examle of a Story_nnnn.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="6.0">
<Story Self="story_2596">
<Content>Headline: 2016 focus on public safety, rank: , word count: 145, photos: 0
As the news year begins, Employees are committed to keeping safety a priority. He said. &quot;We&#39;re committed to safety.&quot;
</Content>
</Story>
</idPkg:Story>
```

I this should be a complete, valid IDML file.

I wish I had this information when I started my project!